# Hibernate saveOrUpdate() method issue

Tags: hibernate

I am using this saveOrUpdate().

```
public void saveObject(Object obj1) {
    //getSession() it returns the current hibernate session
    getSession().clear();
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(obj1);
    getSession().flush();
}
```

**Scenario**

Let's suppose Object obj is my entity class object. and I fetched that object from the database through HQL.

Now I am placed that obj into our application session and I made some changes in this obj.

now I want to save that obj into the database.

While saving I checked whether this obj is created before 8 hr

if yes 
then I create new Object obj1 and copy all the properties with changes in newly created obj1

and passes that obj1 to saveOrupdate(); methods

**Problem.**

It saved obj and obj1 both even though we are not passing obj to save method.